# Pagerank vs Eigenvector centrality

Tags: eigenvalues, networks, social-network

What are the practical differences between PageRank and Eigenvector centralities? I don't mean the differents in how to compute the centralities, but the information they provide of a set of nodes in a network. Could you set an example?

Comment: I guess the most obvious difference is that PageRank is a variant for directed networks, whereas the classic eigenvector centrality is for undirected.

Answer (score 5):

`Eigenvector centrality` is undirected, and `PageRank` applies for directed network. However, `PageRank` uses the `indegree` as the main measure to estimate the influence level, thus it turns to be a very specific case or variant of `Eigenvector centrality`.

Comment: This has always been my understanding too but igraph has eigenvector_centrality and allows you to toggle directed=T or F, and the default is directed! Doesn't this conflict with the notion that eigenvector is for undirected only?

Puzzled by this
https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#eigenvector_centrality

Comment: JE52, you are right, igraph has adapted the algorithm to the directed mode, likewise, the  text says that it is proportional to the sum of degrees pointing to a vertex, therefore, quite the same idea of pagerank.

Comment: Thank you for confirming!